# How do I run this function on multiple elements on one page?

Tags: javascript

This works for the first element only.  How do I make it work for all of them?  Sticking with vanilla javascript.

```js
var timeElement = document.querySelector('.datepublished > time'),
time = new Date(timeElement.getAttribute('datetime'));

timeElement.innerText = TimeAgo.inWords(time.getTime());
```

```html
<div class="datepublished"><time datetime="2017-07-04">date</time></div>
<div class="datepublished"><time datetime="2017-08-04">date</time></div>
<div class="datepublished"><time datetime="2017-09-04">date</time></div>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` + a loop?

Comment: I'm trying but I can't get the loop right...  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```js
var func = function(el) {
  // TimeAgo removed for compatibility
  el.innerText = new Date(el.getAttribute('datetime')).getTime();
}

// Variant 1 //

var dates = document.getElementsByClassName('datepublished');

for (var node of dates) {
  func(node.getElementsByTagName('time')[0]);
}

// Variant 2 //

var dates = document.querySelectorAll('.datepublished > time');

for (var node of dates) {
  func(node);
}
```

```html
<div class="datepublished">
  <time datetime="2017-07-04">date</time>
</div>
<div class="datepublished">
  <time datetime="2017-08-04">date</time>
</div>
<div class="datepublished">
  <time datetime="2017-09-04">date</time>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all elements with a selector, you have to use

```
document.querySelectorAll ("yourSelector")
```

For further information, take a look on this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp